# errorCode": "6000" - azure synapse running the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I have error when running a pipeline in azure synapse. If I execute the synapse notebook manually it works good (readind and writing). But when I call the name notebook from the ForEach activity inside the pipeline it fails to run. I have the following error. Previously, I had no porblem.

```
Error
{
    "errorCode": "6000",
    "message": "{\n  \"code\": 400,\n  \"message\": \"Failed to run notebook due to invalid request. [Error: Not supported language in Synapse: ]\",\n  \"result\": {\n    \"errorMessage\": null,\n    \"details\": null\n  }\n}",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "1 - Full load Parquet",
    "details": []
}
```

Maybe worth to mention that, If I run first cmd i notebook manually and then trigger the pipeline, it run perfectly. So I dont know why but I requires the manuall start of engine?

Comment: How you are assigning notebook name in Notebook activity? Is it reflecting the name in Notebook activity? or you have given the name using dynamic content?

Comment: so I have a notebook activity inside the ForEach Activity. When I click notebook, under Settings tab I have Notebook name where Im referencing the synapse notebook by clicking a drop dwon arrow and chooseing the desired notebook. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: can you show your Notebook activity configurations inside ForEach?

Comment: sure, https://imgur.com/a/wjc42QB

Comment: Did your Notebook run? Check this once in apache spark applications log.

Comment: Pipeline is running now too with no problem but only after i run the notebook cmd manually.